# Gtk Notebook call function every time a certain tab is selected

Tags: python, gtk, gtk3

I want a tab on my notebook that pretty much does the same like a button. Every time I select this tab it should execute a certain job (for example print('something') ).

How do I get it to execute every time I open it? Right now it just executes once on startup and that's it.

If someone has some advice on this subject I'd really apreciate some help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the [`switch-page` signal](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gtk-3.0/classes/Notebook.html#Gtk.Notebook.signals.switch_page):

```
def callback(notebook, tab, index):
    if index == index_of_the_tab:
        print('selected')

    # alternatively:
    # if tab is the_tab:
    #     print('selected')

notebook.connect('switch-page', callback)
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer is very useful. How do we utilize a method like this when the current tab is reselected? In my case, I want to utilize the callback when a different tab is selected (Solved by your answer) as well as when the current tab is selected yet again.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [**`switch-page`**](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkNotebook.html#GtkNotebook-switch-page) signal.

The callback prototype includes the page number id so that you can figure out to which page you are switching.

> void user_function (GtkNotebook *notebook,
>                  GtkWidget   *page,
>                  guint        page_num,
>                  gpointer     user_data)